# Vaadin List of checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin

I'm new about Vaadin.

I have to create a list of checkbox Item.

Is possible to use some exist List Vaadin components where I can invoke some method like addItem?

I have to use v. 6.7.7 Vaadin version.

Comment: Depends on your layout. But probably you justuse a VerticalLayout and in a loop create a CheckBox and use addComponent(cb) to it.

Comment: Can't you just use OptionGroup and define setMultiSelect(true) for it?

Comment: I need to have scroll vertical indicator: Is possible to have these using OptionGroup or VerticalLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Vaadin 6]**

There are many possible ways to do this. In example you can use OptionGroup together with Panel:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    Window mainWindow = new Window("So9 Application");
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    Panel panel = new Panel("Panel");
    VerticalLayout panelLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    OptionGroup optionGroup = new OptionGroup();
    panel.setHeight("200px");
    panel.setWidth("200px");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        optionGroup.addItem(i);
    }
    panelLayout.addComponent(optionGroup);
    panel.setContent(panelLayout);
    layout.addComponent(panel);
    mainWindow.addComponent(layout);
    setMainWindow(mainWindow);
}
```

This code creates 10 checkboxes on a Panel with vertical scrollbar. OptionGroup is added to VerticalLayout which is a content of the Panel which is added to VerticalLayout which is the main layout of mainWindow.

Comment: I have an error when I set the content of Panel: panel.setContent(optionGroup); The method setContent(ComponentContainer) in the type Panel is not applicable for the arguments (OptionGroup). I use vaadin 6.7.7 and Java 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it recently. https://gist.github.com/Peppe-/a077f100c06b9d6f3b09

It is for Vaadin 7 and uses CustomField to wrap a VerticalLayout with CheckBoxes into a Field of it's own. If I recall correctly, Vaadin 6 has an add-on for CustomField instead of a built-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a vertical list of CheckBoxes, and having a scroll bar, you can use Table with [CheckBox components inside it](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html#components.table.features.components).

Note that, just to get a vertical scroll bar, you can put any component (or a layout) inside a Panel, so that the height of the panel is defined (fixed or relative, but not undefined); if the content grows higher than the panel's content area, scrollbar(s) will appear. You could, for example, put an OptionGroup inside a Panel. Just note the this does not scale well to hundreds or more items; for such cases, the Table solution is better.

Comment: Ok, I tryed to use a Panel with OptionGroup component inside a Panel but I obtain an error when I set the content of my Panel: mypanel.setContent(myOptionGroup);
I can't use a OptionGroup as parameter of setContent method of Panel. How can I solve this?